# Entity Framework Core 3.1.3 (PostgreSQL) Creating a PostgreSQL query using (AND OR)

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have the following EF Core query:

```
        var instancesForCustomer = (from v in loyalty.VoucherAuthentication
                                    where v.CardNumber == cardNumber
                                    && v.InstanceType == instanceType
                                    && v.PreAuthorised == false
                                    && v.Redeemed == false 
                                    && v.VoucherExpiryDate > Functions.GenerateDateTimeByLocale()
                                    && v.PreAuthExpiryDate > Functions.GenerateDateTimeByLocale()
                                    select v).AsNoTracking().ToArray();
```

However I would like the query to contain the following condition, rather than just:

```
*WHERE PreAuthExpiry > Now*
```

To be

```
*WHERE (PreAuthExpiry > Now OR PreAuthExpiry IS NULL)*
```

I'm unclear how to create the query so that the > `Now` and the `IS NULL` are considered in their own block, rather than assessing all the prior conditions against EITHER `PreAuthExpiry > Now` or `IS NULL`.  If It's just OR PreAuthExpiry IS NULL, then all records with NULL PreAuthExpiry will come back, ignoring the other AND conditions.

Comment: `&& (v.PreAuthExpiryDate == null || v.PreAuthExpiryDate > Functions.GenerateDateTimeByLocale())`

Comment: Ah, thank you mjwills! I didn't realise that ef core accepted direct translation of the '(' and ')' brackets. I couldn't find any examples of that when searching. Thank you, I'll test.